# Hide navigation bar in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

Can anyone tell me how to hide the navigation bar in my storyboard. My code below is working fine when running in the simulator but it still appears in my storyboard which is really annoying me as it's messing around with the placement of my images. Can anyone help?

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: For everyone trying to figure out how to hide the navbar **for a particular view controller** from the storyboard...this is not possible. **BUT**, there is a good reason for this. The expected way is to first simply hide/show the navbar programmatically (something like `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated`), **then** in your storyboard, adjust the `Simulated Metrics > Top Bar` for each individual view controller so that its appearance reflects what currently happens from your code...

Comment: ...Because the purpose of those Simulated Metrics is so you can get an idea of what your view will look like based on the code whose effects you can't "see" yet.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[image]

Click on the controller that has the top bar navigate to the properties bar on the right hand side of Xcode. There is a drop down labeled Top Bar (as shown above) change this drop down to none.

Comment: I think this is the same answer the first.

Comment: It was added while i was typing

Comment: What if i want it per view controller?

Comment: Is anyone successful in per view controller navigation hiding and showing.

Comment: @VanDuTran See my comment on OPs original question (above).

Answer (score 12):

You have to click the actual navigation controller, not the view controller. On the view controller the navigation drop down doesn't show up, but you can still achieve this by selecting Top Bar: none in Simulated Metrics.

[image: Top Bar: None]

Comment: Then it isn't for an individual view controller.

Answer (score 10):

In the Storyboard view, just select the NavigationController scene and UNCHECK Shows Navigation Bar (Attributes Inspector)

Comment: this applies to all of its children though - wont work if you only want to hide one

Answer (score 8):

Solution for the same using **Swift 3:**

*Step 1.* Using attribute inspector hide Navigation Bar from Storyboard:
[image]

*Step 2.* Add the following code to your `ViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: This is just the swift 3 equivalent of what the OP has shown. This does _not_ hide the navigation bar **in the storyboard**. It does. however, hide the navigation bar when running the app.

Comment: @Tim that's what it is supposedly do.

Comment: It is not what the OP asked.

Comment: @Tim you might want to read the question again. He mentioned that navbar is still appearing in storyboard, that he doesn’t want.

Comment: _Can anyone tell me how to hide the navigation bar in my storyboard. My code below is working fine when running in the simulator** but it still appears in my storyboard**_ I have read the question. Despite it being 6 years old. The OP asked how to hide the navbar within the storyboard.

Answer (score 5):

```
Follow these step:    
    1: Go to storyboard
    2: Select navigation controller
    3: Goto Attribute inspector
    4: Under navigation controller bar visibility **Uncheck the Shows navigation Bar***
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For specific ViewController, set the topbar as `none`

[image]

Comment: This answers the OPs question, but if you're scrolling through and trying to find the answer to how to hide the nav bar for a particular view controller FROM the storyboard (not just while viewing the storyboard), unfortunately this is not possible. See my comment to the OPs original question (at the top) for why this is the case.