# Collection View in View Controller, Cell touching the top border of Collection View itself (embedded in navigation controller)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

so, i'm trying to make horizontal scroll collection view in view controller. The View Controller is embedded in navigation controller. So the view controller have little spacing on top of cell. And if i resize it, the cell gonna sink. Simply, i want the little spacing dissapear. Normally like Collection View inside view controller without embedded in navigation controller

i want this
[image: i want this:]

to this
[image: to this]

i want this

Comment: Is the space on the top supposed to be the space for the navigation bar? Are you using the default navigation bar of the navigation controller? Or have you set it to hidden = YES?

Comment: yes, but i don't want to put it under navigation bar. I didn't set the Hidden. also i'm using navigation bar from object library and delete the default table view that come with navigation controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620471/hide-navigation-bar-in-storyboard   Use this to hide the navigation bar. And the just move the collectionview upwards. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Embed a navigation bar  and then drag the collection view. This should hopefully work. If it doesn't let me know..